# how to install pyi file into site-packages root dir?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-typing, python-packaging

I am trying to setup a stub typing file for a module that sits in the site-package (uno.py) root dir.

I have created a `uno.pyi` file in the root of my project and I am at a loss how to create a setup that installs into site-packages root dir where uno.py resides.

I am using a setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = uno-stubs
version = 0.0.3
author = somebody
author_email = me@mail.me
description = Type annotations for uno
long_description = file:README.rst
long_description_content_type = text/x-rst
url = https://github.com/Amourspirit/does-not-exist
classifiers =
    License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
    Environment :: Other Environment
    Intended Audience :: Developers
    Operating System :: OS Independent
    Topic :: Office/Business
    Typing :: Typed
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10

[options]
packages = find:
include_package_data = True
package_data =
    * = uno.pyi
python_requires = >=3.7
install_requires =
    typing_extensions>=3.7.4.3;python_version<"3.7"
    types-unopy>=0.1.5

[options.packages.find]
exclude =
    build*
    dist*
    docs*
    tests*
    cmds*
    env*
    src*
    tmp*

[options.extras_require]

    # local

[options.entry_points]
```

I have a MANIFEST.in file

```
include uno.pyi
```

So far I have no luck getting `uno.pyi` to install into site-packages root dir.

`uno.pyi` is in my project root folder.

Project Structure:

```
UNO_PYI
|
|--setup.py
|--setup.cfg
|--MANIFEST.in
|--uno.pyi
|--README.rst
|--LICENSE
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptor before using a tag.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a directory with the same name as the module.
This allowed me to put a **init**.pyi file in the dir to gain typings.

See [LibreOffice UNO Typings](https://github.com/Amourspirit/python-types-uno-script) for entire solution.

```
UNO_PYI
|
|--uno
   |--__init__.pyi
|--setup.py
|--README.rst
|--LICENSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setup.py` and build wheels. Despite the `setup.cfg` is recommanded, as of today it provides poor support for basic stuff.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/szabolcsdombi/zengl/blob/67afe6f6ee96a2cfef8d6a299869b4b36675573d/setup.py#L28) to get pyi files distributet along your module/extension.

```py
setup(
    name=...,
    version=...,
    py_modules=['uno'],
    data_files=[('.', ['uno.pyi'])],
    ...
)
```